# include multiple javascript code using php

Tags: javascript, html

I want to include this code multiple times in the same page using php (include).
**html code:**

```
<div class="red" onclick="red()">red</div>
<div class="green" onclick="green()">green</div>
<div class="blue" onclick="blue()">blue</div>
<div id="change">click on the colors to change the div color</div>
```

**css code:**

```
.red{background-color: red;width: 50px;}
.green{background-color: green;width: 50px;}
.blue{background-color: blue;width: 50px;}
#change{background-color: yellow;width: 100px;}
```

**javascript code:**

```
function red()
{
document.getElementById('change').style.background="red";
}
function green()
{
document.getElementById('change').style.background="green";
}
function blue()
{
document.getElementById('change').style.background="blue";
}
```

This code works fine in the first div (id=change) but in the second div when I click on the div with class=red it changes the first div instead of the second.
How can I make it change the div that is below it?
**problem solved:**
http://jsfiddle.net/wjp4pqw6/1/

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute defined. The results are undefined as to what the browser should do in that situation, but as you are seeing, it typically uses the first one it finds in the HTML document.

Comment: what is the purpose of these codes ? you can assign a div id to a single div.  otherwise how can JS determine which div it change the color ?

Comment: @MarcBaumbach How can I make it use the nearest div to it? I have tried getElmentByTagName('div')[3] but it still use the div with index of (3).

Comment: @AthulAK I want to use a code similar to this in a forum to allow the user to include it multiple times in a post.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to accomplish this, one is to provide a unique ID and pass it into the functions you are calling (See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wjp4pqw6/)). I would normally recommend something that is more [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) though.

Comment: you only want change the second div's color or to change all 'change' div in that page by clicking any color tab in same page ? like this http://jsfiddle.net/athullive/5jw858nt/ ??

Comment: @MarcBaumbach I can't change the id because the same code will be included multiple times.

Comment: @AthulAK just the second div.

Comment: You can try something more flexible like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1a5co293/). This example uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) though because I'm too lazy to do it in vanilla JS. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have written some code that should do it for you:

**PHP**

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    echo '<div id="containter_'.$i.'">';
    echo '<div class="red" onclick="color(\'red\', this);" id="red_'.$i.'">red</div>';
    echo '<div class="green" id="green_'.$i.'" onclick="color(\'green\', this)">green</div>';
    echo '<div class="blue" id="blue_'.$i.'" onclick="color(\'blue\', this)">blue</div>';
    echo '<div class="change" id="change_'.$i.'"></div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

That echo's 10 blocks of your code.

**Javascript**

```
function color(c, elem) {
    id = elem.id.replace(c,'');
    document.getElementById('change'+id).style.background=c;
}
```

**CSS**

```
.red{background-color: red;width: 50px;}
.green{background-color: green;width: 50px;}
.blue{background-color: blue;width: 50px;}
.change{background-color: yellow;width: 100px;}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="red">red</div>
    <div class="green">green</div>
    <div class="blue">blue</div>
    <div class="change">click on the colors to change the div color</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="red">red</div>
    <div class="green">green</div>
    <div class="blue">blue</div>
    <div class="change">click on the colors to change the div color</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.red{background-color: red;width: 50px;}
.green{background-color: green;width: 50px;}
.blue{background-color: blue;width: 50px;}
.change{background-color: yellow;width: 100px;}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
    $.each(colors, function() {
        var color = this;
        $("." + color).click(function() {
            $(this).siblings(".change").css("background", color)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What's the point of copy pasting the code given in the comments above by @MarcBaumbach?

Comment: it'll help other users to use the answer. users never look for comments, but answers.